# Error compiling source code at Java

Tags: java, sublimetext2

I have this code:

```
package org.test;

import org.test.utils.Logger;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

At file:

```
/var/www/test/src/org/test/Test.java
```

And this other file:

```
package org.test.utils;

public class Logger
{

}
```

At file:

```
/var/www/test/src/org/test/utils/Logger.java
```

But when I compile it from sublime, it says:

```
Compiling Java sourcecode...
Test.java:3: error: package org.test.utils does not exist
import org.test.utils.Logger;
                     ^
1 error
Compiling error, no .class file created
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

I'm using this manual: http://binarydaydreams.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/compiling-java-with-sublimetext2-on-ubuntu/

I'm newbbie at Java... What am I doing wrong?

***Edit 1***

Java Information

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

*** Edit 2 ***

If I try to compile only the logger file, the error is this:

```
Compiling Java sourcecode...
Running the compiled code...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Logger (wrong name: org/test/utils/Logger)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:788)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: How are you running your `javac` command? And from which directory.

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: The manual you linked to is wrong, it runs javac from the wrong directory. I recommend that you first compile your code from a command line, then write scripts or makefiles to simplify the process.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. I followed one manual to install java from oracle and have it as the default java compiler

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your `Logger` class as `Loger` (1 "g").

Change the declaration as:

```
public class Logger
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see the error is another one. You are right, I realized it but still don't compiled